# Java Web Start manifest issue

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jnlp

Im trying to make a swing-app redistributable via java web start. Im building jar and jnlp with netbeans 7.4.

Im getting this message when application is downloaded via web.(Sorry for spanish)
But it says that manifest.mf doesn't contain permission attributes.

[image]

Im not using a trusted certificated (by CA) i created keystore by my own with netbeans tool.

In `project.properties` i put

```
# Optional override of default Codebase manifest attribute, use to prevent RIAs from being repurposed
manifest.custom.codebase=http://150.1.1.32:8084/
# Optional override of default Permissions manifest attribute (supported values: sandbox, all-permissions)
manifest.custom.permissions=all-permissions
manifest.file=manifest.mf
```

And when i see after build jar manifest from main jar and all dependencies jar has the attribute `all-permissions`

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.7.0_45-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.onix.sirf.gui.executors.SwingExecutor
Codebase: http://150.1.1.32:8084/
```

This is my `jnlp`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://150.1.1.32:8084/" href="sirf.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>title</title>
        <vendor>blabla</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.blabla.com"/>
        <description>Some description</description>
        <description kind="short">HelloWorld</description>
    </information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="frontend.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar"/>
 -- there are some more libraries
<extension href="jnlpcomponent1.jnlp"/> -- here is one more library sqljdbc4.jar
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.onix.sirf.gui.executors.SwingExecutor">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

And `jnlpcomponent1.jnlp`

```
<jnlp codebase="http://150.1.1.32:8084/" href="jnlpcomponent1.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>jnlpcomponent1</title>
        <vendor>MSFTSIG</vendor>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <jar href="lib/sqljdbc4.jar" download="eager"/>
    </resources>
    <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

In `jnlpcomponent1.jnlp`  i see that `sqljdbc4.jar` is already signed by microsoft.

When i was looking to its `manifest.mf` it hasn't the attribute `Permissions: all-permissions`. So i delete all manifest file from `sqljdbc4.jar` and put an empty one (delete `MSFTSIG.SF` and `MSFTSIG.RSA` also). Build application again now with my signature and with `Permissions: all-permissions` in manifest file and works like a charm.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20883491/875512) suggests a potentially simpler way of updating your manifest files.