# Java Security Warning

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, code-signing, jnlp

I'm running my java app using web start , through jnlp.

However even if it's signed, I'm still seeing this warning. Also there's no "Do not show this again for this app" checkbox .

Any ideas as to what is missing ?

Thanks,

Below is a attached a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Is your app self signed ?

Comment: CN=thawte Primary Root CA,... seems to be the signing authority

Comment: What about the third party jars that you are using ? You have to update the jar manifest for the third-party libraries that are used as well !

Comment: That I haven't considered so fa. Still it might not be as easy to since there are ~20 thirdparty jars. Would I need to obtain new jars with updated manifest or should it be me the one that rebuilds the jars ?

Comment: You can use the old jars but you need to strip out the signing info in the manifest.mf, or completely replace the manifest.mf if doesn't have any specific info in it.  We have a process that unzips the jars, removes the manifest.mf, re-jars and then signs each of our 3rd party jars.   The tricky part is if there is info in the manifest.mf for stuff like service loading, found in jdbc jars.

Comment: Please trim the huge white space to the right of that screen shot.  Or better, retype all the text and include that as an edit.  The output of the dialogs is unexpected to me - in that it acknowledges the code is signed by a cert. from a trusted source, yet fails to include the `always allow` check box.  I would expect the check box to be included in the first dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that all your third party jars are also signed. For more details please have a look at the link

[How to publish a Java Web Start jnlp application without security warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665971/how-to-publish-a-java-web-start-jnlp-application-without-security-warnings)