# Java Web Start- permissions attribute warning

Tags: java, security, manifest, java-web-start, manifest.mf

I am trying to run a Java Web Start application developed by me but when I run the jnlp, I get a security warning about the ***"Permissions" attribute being missing in the Manifest*** and the application does not run. I'm unable to understand why this happens as my manifest has the permissions attribute set in it using the line:

> Permissions: all-permissions

Why is it then that running the Web Start says that the **permissions** attribute is missing ? Do I also have to include the attribute in ***every jar*** (in 'lib') that my code uses. If so, **how** do I modify 3rd party jars & set the permissions attribute in the Manifest ? Feedback on how to resolve this issue would be great. Thanks.

**Update [16/07/14]:**
I've now added the **Application-Name** attribute in my jar's ***manifest*** file and re-signed it. When I run the jnlp now, there is no manifest permissions warning. I have left the 3rd party jars untouched  so far. However, when the application starts the WebStart Console still states: "**Missing Application-Name manifest attribute**" & "**Missing permissions manifest attribute**". How do I solve this problem ?

**Latest Update [18/07/14]**
Hi, I've managed to make my **WebStart** application run. However, it now first brings up a popup with the jar & its certificate's details. It then shows another popup with an error. I saw a post here with the same issue at [Java Web Start manifest issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431623/java-web-start-manifest-issue) which provides the following solution:

> In jnlpcomponent1.jnlp i see that sqljdbc4.jar is already signed by microsoft.
>
> When i was looking to its manifest.mf it hasn't the attribute Permissions: all-permissions. So i delete all manifest file from sqljdbc4.jar and put an empty one (delete MSFTSIG.SF and MSFTSIG.RSA also). Build application again now with my signature and with Permissions: all-permissions in manifest file and works like a charm.

In my application, the '**jnlpcomponent1.jnlp**' file contains four ***3rd party jars*** that are already signed. My question is how do I **unpack** these jar's (to replace the **Manifest** with a blank one & delete the .SF and .HSA files) & **re-pack** it ? Please let me know. Thanks.

**Update [21/07/14]:** I have managed to resolve this issue myself.
Thanks.

Comment: *"Do I also have to include the permissions attribute in every jar"* Yes.

Comment: This is regarding another error in the same application. In my application, the '**jnlpcomponent1.jnlp**' file contains four ***3rd party jars*** that are already signed. My question is how do I **unpack** these jar's (to replace the **Manifest** with a blank one & delete the .SF and .HSA files) & **re-pack** it ? Please let me know. Thanks.