# Java WebStart - 3rd party jar - manifest

Tags: java, java-web-start, manifest.mf

I'm trying to run a Java **WebStart** application using Netbeans IDE. I've signed the application using a valid Comodo certificate. When I run the jar, it brings up a popup with the jar & its certificate's details. However, it then shows another popup with an error. I saw a post here with the same issue at [Java Web Start manifest issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431623/java-web-start-manifest-issue) which provides the following solution:

> I solved it.
>
> In jnlpcomponent1.jnlp i see that sqljdbc4.jar is already signed by microsoft.
>
> When i was looking to its manifest.mf it hasn't the attribute Permissions: all-permissions. So i delete all manifest file from sqljdbc4.jar and put an empty one (delete MSFTSIG.SF and MSFTSIG.RSA also). Build application again now with my signature and with Permissions: all-permissions in manifest file and works like a charm.

In my application, the '**jnlpcomponent1.jnlp**' file contains four ***3rd party jars*** that are already signed. My question is how do I **unpack** these jar's (to replace the **Manifest** with a blank one & delete the .SF and .DSA files) & **re-pack** it ?

Is there a way to manually do it (e.g., at **command prompt**) ? Can I manually unpack these 4 jars, edit their **Manifest**, remove the .SF & .DSA files and re-pack them ? Please let me know. Thanks.

**Update:** I have managed to resolve the issue today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly how you would do it in netbeans, however if you were using a build system (such as gradle) to manage everything for the webstart, then you could add the line to your jar task in your build.gradle that looks like:

```
jar{
    from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }

    manifest{
        attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName);
    }
}
```

that takes every dependency (the third party jars) unpacks (unzips) them and then packs (zips) them back up into a single jar next to your own, along with all of their manifest/etc files. There is a gradle plugin for netbeans (we use at work with great success), but it would obviously take some work to convert your project over, just something to keep in mind. I hope that helps in any small way.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But, is there a way to manually do this (e.g., at command prompt) ? Can I manually unpack these 4 jars, edit their Manifest, remove the .SF & .DSA files and re-pack them ? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: can you? sure, a jar is just a glorified zip file, really. Just make sure that you preserve all of the file structures very carefully.